# Formulario de paciente con imagen

Tags: java, angular, typescript, spring-boot, imagen

Estoy haciendo un proyecto con Angular y Springboot donde...
Estoy implementando la carga de los pacientes con imagen en el formulario.
El problema que me esta surgiendo es el siguiente:

ERROR:

> POST http://localhost:8080/api/v1/paciente/crearPaciente 400 (Bad
> Request)

DESCRIPCION DEL ERROR:

> HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400, statusText:
> 'OK', url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/paciente/crearPaciente', ok:
> false, …} error :  {timestamp: 1708545115937, status: 400, error: 'Bad
> Request', trace:
> 'org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodAr…onverter(ConversionUtils.java:41)\r\n\t...
> 95 more\r\n', message: `Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String'…":"","dni":0,"tipo_sangre":"","ti (truncated)...]`,
> …} headers :  HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null,
> lazyInit: ƒ} message :  "Http failure response for
> http://localhost:8080/api/v1/paciente/crearPaciente: 400 OK" name :
> "HttpErrorResponse" ok :  false status :  400 statusText :  "OK" url :
> "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/paciente/crearPaciente" [[Prototype]] :
> HttpResponseBase

**BACKEND:**

*En mi application properties:*

```
file.upload-dir=C:\Users\Lautaro\Desktop\Proyectos\proyecto-clinica-odontologica\imagen
```

*Imagen service:*

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ImagenServiceImpl implements ImagenService {

    @Value("${file.upload-dir}")
    private String uploadDir;

    @Override
    public void guardarImagen(Integer id, MultipartFile file, String imageName) throws IOException {
        Path entityDir = Paths.get(uploadDir, "user_" + id);
        Path filePath = entityDir.resolve(imageName);

        Files.createDirectories(entityDir); // Asegurar que el directorio exista
        file.transferTo(filePath); // Guardar el archivo en el directorio
    }


    @Override
    public byte[] cargarImagen(Integer id, String imagen) throws IOException {
        Path imagePath = Paths.get(uploadDir, "user_" + id, imagen);
        return Files.readAllBytes(imagePath);
    }
}
```

*En mi paciente service:*

```
 @Override
    public Paciente guardarImagen(Integer id, MultipartFile file) {

        Paciente paciente = repository.findById(id).orElse(null);

        if (paciente != null) {
            try {
                if (file != null && !file.isEmpty()) {
                    String imageName = "imagen_paciente_" + paciente.getId() + "_" + file.getOriginalFilename();
                    imagenService.guardarImagen(paciente.getId(), file,imageName);
                    paciente.setImgUrl(imageName); // Almacenar la ruta de la imagen en el campo imgUrl
                    return repository.save(paciente);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Manejar la excepción de manera adecuada (puedes lanzarla o loguearla según tus necesidades)
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null; // Puedes manejar este caso de acuerdo a tus necesidades (puedes lanzar una excepción, loguear, etc.)
    }
```

Donde despues utilizo el guardar imagen en el siguiente servicio , guardar paciente:

```
  @Override
    public Paciente crearPacienteConHistorial(Paciente paciente, MultipartFile file) {
        User user = userService.findByEmail(paciente.getEmail()).orElse(null);

        if(user != null){
            paciente.setUser(user);
        }

        // Crear y guardar el historial médico
        HistorialMedico historialMedico = new HistorialMedico();
        // Configurar propiedades específicas del historial médico
        historialMedico.setPaciente(paciente); // Establecer la relación inversa al paciente

        // Guardar el historial médico en la base de datos
        historialMedicoService.saveHistorial(historialMedico);

        // Configurar otras propiedades del paciente según los datos en pacienteRequest
        paciente.setHistorialMedico(historialMedico);

        //Guardamos la imagen del paciente
        guardarImagen(paciente.getId(),file);

        // Guardar el paciente en la base de datos
        return repository.save(paciente);

    }
```

*En mi contoller:*

```
@PostMapping("/crearPaciente")
    public ResponseEntity<Paciente> crearPaciente(
            @RequestParam Paciente pacienteRequest,
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

        try {
            Paciente paciente = service.crearPacienteConHistorial(pacienteRequest, file);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(paciente, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

**FRONTEND:**

Servicio para guardar el paciente:

```
 crearPacienteConHistorial(paciente: Paciente, file: File): Observable<Paciente> {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file, file.name);
    formData.append('pacienteRequest', JSON.stringify(paciente));

    const headers = new HttpHeaders();

    return this.http.post<Paciente>(`${this.apiUrl}/crearPaciente`, formData, { headers: headers });
  }
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="container mt-4">
    <h2>Alta de Paciente</h2>
    <form (ngSubmit)= "crearPaciente()" #altaPacienteForm="ngForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" [(ngModel)]= "nuevoPaciente.nombre" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="apellido">Apellido</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellido" name="apellido" [(ngModel)]= "nuevoPaciente.apellido" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fechaNacimiento">Fecha de Nacimiento</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fechaNacimiento" name="fechaNacimiento" [(ngModel)]= "nuevoPaciente.fechaNacimiento" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="telefono">Teléfono</label>
        <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="telefono" name="telefono" [(ngModel)]= "nuevoPaciente.telefono" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" [(ngModel)]= "nuevoPaciente.email" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="dni">DNI</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="dni" name="dni" [(ngModel)]= "nuevoPaciente.dni" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="direccion">Dirección</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="direccion" name="direccion" [(ngModel)]= "nuevoPaciente.direccion" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="tipoSangre">Tipo de Sangre</label>
        <select class="form-select" id="tipoSangre"  name = "tipoSangre" [(ngModel)]= "nuevoPaciente.tipo_sangre">
          <option value="" selected></option>
          <option *ngFor="let tipo of tipoSangreOptions" [value]= "tipo">{{ tipo }}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="tiene_OS">¿Tiene Obra Social?</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="tiene_OS" name="tiene_OS" [(ngModel)]= "nuevoPaciente.tiene_OS">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" *ngIf= "nuevoPaciente.tiene_OS">
        <label for="obraSocial">Obra Social</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="obraSocial" name="obraSocial" [(ngModel)]= "nuevoPaciente.obraSocial" required>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="imagen">Seleccionar Imagen:</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="imagen" name="imagen"  [(ngModel)]= "nuevoPaciente.img" (change)="onFileSelected($event)" accept="image/*">
      </div>


      
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar Paciente</button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PacienteService } from '../paciente.service';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-alta-pacientes',
    templateUrl: './alta-pacientes.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./alta-pacientes.component.scss']
})
export class AltaPacientesComponent implements OnInit {
    nuevoPaciente: any = {};
    selectedImage!: File;
    tipoSangreOptions: string[] = ['A+', 'O+', 'B+', 'AB+', 'A-', 'O-', 'B-', 'AB-'];
    nuevoPacienteForm!: FormGroup;  // Agregamos un FormGroup para manejar el formulario

    constructor(
        private service: PacienteService,
        private toastr: ToastrService,
        private router: Router,
        private fb: FormBuilder,  // Inyectamos FormBuilder
    ) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        // Inicializamos el FormGroup con validadores si es necesario
        this.nuevoPacienteForm = this.fb.group({
            nombre: ['', Validators.required],
            apellido: ['', Validators.required],
            telefono: ['', Validators.required],
            direccion: ['', Validators.required],
            obraSocial: ['', Validators.required],
            dni: [0, Validators.required],
            tipo_sangre: ['', Validators.required],
            tiene_OS: [false, Validators.required],
            fechaNacimiento: [new Date(0, 0, 0), Validators.required],
            email: ['', Validators.required],
            // Otros campos del formulario...
            img: [''],
        });
    }

    onFileSelected(event: any): void {
        this.selectedImage = event.target.files[0] as File;
    }

    crearPaciente(): void {
        // Usamos this.nuevoPacienteForm.value en lugar de this.nuevoPaciente
        this.service.crearPacienteConHistorial(this.nuevoPacienteForm.value, this.selectedImage).subscribe(response => {
            console.log("Guardado con éxito", response);
            this.mostrarNotificacion();
            this.volverPacientes();
        });
    }

    mostrarNotificacion() {
        this.toastr.success('Paciente guardado con éxito', 'Éxito');
    }

    volverPacientes() {
        this.router.navigate(['/component/pacientes']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Me falto agregar esto :    2024-02-21T18:58:55.931-03:00  WARN 836 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.backend.CRUD.Entity.Paciente'; Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Integer] for value [{"nombre":"","apellido":"","telefono":"","direccion":"","obraSocial":"","dni":0,"tipo_sangre":"","ti (truncated)...]]